# System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'somefile.txt' because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#

I am trying to open a file in read-only mode. The file is created by another application that is still running and probably it is kept open by that application. However, I am able to open the file using a text editor such as Notepad. Why can't read from the file in read-only mode?

```
        string file = @"c:\temp\somefile.txt";
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(file);  
        
        int len = (int)fi.Length;

        char[] chars = new char[len];
        var fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        
        int numBytesToRead = (int)fs.Length;
        int numBytesRead = 0;               
        
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(fs))
        {
            int n = sr.Read(chars, numBytesRead, len);
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use one of the overloads of the [`FileStream` constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream?view=netcore-3.1#constructors) that accepts a [`FileShare`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileshare?view=netcore-3.1) parameter.

Basically, all of the open file handles have to agree - your `FileAccess` has to be compatible with their `FileShare` and your `FileShare` has to be compatible with their `FileAccess` (of course, I'm using .NET names here but these map to core Windows concepts common to all programs).

It seems likely you'll want to make your `FileShare` `ReadWrite`, to maximize the chances of interoperating with the other program, if you don't know what access it's using.

Comment: Thanks, I just found the answer. I had to change the line var fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);